# Spring Batch avoid launch Reader and Writer before tasklet

Tags: java, spring, csv, spring-batch

I'm working with spring batch and have a job with two steps the first step (tasklet) validation the header CSV and the second step reads an CSV file and Write to another CSV file like this:

```
@Bean
public ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<POJO> classifierCompositeItemWriter() throws Exception {
    Classifier<POJO, ItemWriter<? super POJO>> classifier = new ClassiItemWriter(ClassiItemWriter.itemWriter());
    return new ClassifierCompositeItemWriterBuilder<POJO>()
            .classifier(classifier)
            .build();
}



@Bean
public Step readAndWriteCsvFile() throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("readAndWriteCsvFile")
            .<POJO, POJO>chunk(10000)
            .reader(ClassitemReader.itemReader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(classifierCompositeItemWriter())
            .build();
}
```

I used a FlatFileItemReader (in ClassitemReader) and a FlatFileItemWriter (in ClassiItemWriter), before reading CSV. I checked if the header of CSV file is correct via tasklet like this :

```
@Bean
public Step fileValidatorStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory
            .get("fileValidatorStep")
            .tasklet(fileValidator)
            .build();
}
```

And if so I process the transformation from CSV file recieved to another file CSV.

in the `jobBuilderFactory` i check if ExistStatus comes from tasklet `fileValidatorStep` is "COMPLETED" to forward the process to `readAndWriteCsvFile()`, if not "COMPLETED" and tasklet `fileValidatorStep` return ExistStatus "ERROR" the job end and exit processing.

```
@Bean
public Job job() throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(fileValidatorStep()).on("ERROR").end()
            .next(fileValidatorStep()).on("COMPLETED").to(readAndWriteCsvFile())
            .end().build();
}
```

The problem is that when I launch my Job the Bean `readAndWriteCsvFile` runs first of the tasklet, that means the standard Bean of reader and writer of spring batch always loaded in life cycle before i can validation the header and check the ExistStatus, the reader is still working and reades the file and puts data in another file without check because is loading Bean during launch of Job before all tasklet.

How i can launch `readAndWriteCsvFile` methode after `fileValidatorStep` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem, i changed the bean `FlatFileItemReader` method inside the Job class configuration with the annotation `@StepScope`, now this bean has only loads when I need it also should avoid declaring the FlatFileItemReader bean out of scope of the job

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a flow job for that, a simple job is enough. Here is a quick example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJobConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Step validationStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("validationStep")
                .tasklet(new Tasklet() {
                    @Override
                    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                        if(!isValid()) {
                            throw new Exception("Invalid file");
                        }
                        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                    }

                    private boolean isValid() {
                        // TODO implement validation logic
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step readAndWriteCsvFile(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("readAndWriteCsvFile")
                .<Integer, Integer>chunk(2)
                .reader(new ListItemReader<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4)))
                .writer(items -> items.forEach(System.out::println))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(validationStep(stepBuilderFactory))
                .next(readAndWriteCsvFile(stepBuilderFactory))
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJobConfiguration.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }

}
```

In this example, if the `validationStep` fails, the next step is will not be executed.

Comment: when i launch test and debug my code the `ClassitemReader.itemReader()` is always execute before the tasklet this is normal behavior ?

Comment: alos the  class `ClassitemReader.itemReader()` contains methode `FlatFileItemReader`

Comment: I believe that's the cause of your issue. This seems a static method and will be called at configuration time. Any reason you need to create this `ClassitemReader` class? I suggest you move the method that creates your `FlatFileItemReader` next to other bean definition methods and it should work.

Comment: yes, you're right i changed them now it's working correctly

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I had 2 step with 2 different `read`. The `read` always ran first than the `process`. Then I used `@Step` annotation in both `read` and it worked.